# I want to make sure the code below includes sequences

Tags: python, sequence

```
def reset_score(game):
    time.sleep(0.5)  # the snake freezes for a moment when hitting a wall then the game resets
    head.goto(0, 0)
    head.direction = "stop"
    score = 0
    # I could not find a way to remove the tails once the snake hit the wall
    # so I moved the tail to somewhere in the screen that is not visible____This is called creativity
    for game in snake_tail:
        game.goto(1000, 1000)
    score_printer.clear()
    score_printer.write("Score: {}  High Score: {}".format(score, high_score), align="center", font=("italic", 24, "normal"))
    snake_tail.clear()
```

is "game.goto(1000,1000)" a tuple? or does this code include any other sequence. I am really not sure about a clear definition of sequence so I am not sure whether these are sequences or not?

Comment: No. Those are two arguments to a function `goto`. It is like calculating area_of_triangle(length, height). A tuple would be function((a,b)).

Comment: Thanks for answering! So is there any other sequence inside the code?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to understand Sequence in brief, The main sequence types in Python are lists, tuples, and range objects. The main differences between these sequence objects are:

1. Lists are mutable and their elements are usually homogeneous (things of the same type making a list of similar objects)
2. Tuples are immutable and their elements are usually heterogeneous (things of different types making a tuple describing a single structure)
3. Range objects are efficient sequences of integers (commonly used for loops), use a small amount of memory, and yield items only when needed.

Also regarding game.goto(), goto() is used to move the turtle(pre-installed Python library that enables users to create pictures and shapes by providing them with a virtual canvas) at x and y coordinates.

I hope it is understandable now.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining so it means that goto() is not a sequence, right?

Comment: Yup, goto is not a sequence.